Why I got reference to internal Livewire file with Volt component?
On Laravel 11 / Livewire 3 site I use Volt class to make some component for image selecting/preview/uploading.
This component has Modelable declaration :
new class extends Component {
use WithFileUploads;

#[Modelable]
public $form;
...

The form has variable declared:
public $uploadedImage;

So when in my Volt component I upload image with code:
$this->form->uploadedImage->store($this->uploadPath)

checking the content of the $uploadedImage var is:
livewire-file:569WrnYiOdWif93aHJKYNewkPwspP6-metaaW5Nb25kYXkuanBn-.jpg

But not object file which is used for store method above. I suppose that is because Modelable declaration is used and in component above internal Laravel file reference is passed. Not sure, is it so?
I found this temporary file under /storage/app/livewire-tmp/ subdirectory
In manuals https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/uploads I did not find in which way I have to move this file under storage, saving reference to this file?
"laravel/framework": "^11.9",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.5",
"livewire/volt": "^1.6"

